# Get posts from multiple pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to fetch most recent posts of several pages using facebook FQL. Here is my query:

```
# https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?fql=SELECT%20message%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%20in%20(755751084454823%2C%20616632928446954)
SELECT message FROM stream WHERE source_id in (755751084454823, 616632928446954)
```

And it returns 0 results. On the other hand, sending exact same query but for a single page ID returns posts for that given query properly. So, those two queries works great:

```
# https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?fql=SELECT%20message%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%20in%20(616632928446954)
SELECT message FROM stream WHERE source_id in (616632928446954)

# https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?fql=SELECT%20message%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%20in%20(755751084454823)
SELECT message FROM stream WHERE source_id in (755751084454823)
```

I can't quite understand why it behaves like that. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get posts from multiple Pages, use separate calls to the feed endpoint with the Graph API. Example code for this can be found in the docs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/page/feed

You can use Batch Request to make those calls faster, it will take as long as the slowest API call in the batch: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests

FQL is deprecated and will stop working in August 2016. You can´t use it in new Apps anymore.